# Loading trustpilot reviews dynamically in Woocommerce

Tags: html, woocommerce, trustpilot

I am trying to integrate the Trustpilot review boxes into my woocommerce product template.

This is the HTML given by Trustpilot (shortened for ease)

```
<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-theme="light" data-sku="652">
```

Trustpilot

How do I get the sku field to be dynamically assigned so I can load this one snippet on all product pages?

I have tried creating a function to get the sku and calling it as a shortcode in place of the data-sku="652" but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lost!

---

***Edit:***

This is the full TrustBox widget code:

```
<!-- TrustBox widget - Product Reviews MultiSource SEO --> 
<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="5763bccae0a06d08e809ecbb" data-businessunit-id="5e7ca7327ce69500013dc75e" data-style-height="700px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-sku="TRUSTPILOT_SKU_VALUE_652">
    <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
</div>
<!-- End TrustBox widget -->
```

Comment: Maybe a little more code would be nice. How you gonna add it by JS or css. I only see a empty div with the class trustpilot-widge

Comment: this is the full snippet `<!-- TrustBox widget - Product Reviews MultiSource SEO -->
<div class="trustpilot-widget" data-locale="en-GB" data-template-id="5763bccae0a06d08e809ecbb" data-businessunit-id="5e7ca7327ce69500013dc75e" data-style-height="700px" data-style-width="100%" data-theme="light" data-sku="TRUSTPILOT_SKU_VALUE_652">
  <a href="https://uk.trustpilot.com/review/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Trustpilot</a>
</div>
<!-- End TrustBox widget -->` I need a way to make the sku dynamic if possible

Comment: But where is the JS code for setting the innerHtml? Or maybe I misunderstand your question?

Comment: the JS is set by Trustpilot. I'm just trying to figure out a quick and simple way to replace the sku= with the sku from whatever product the widget is loaded on. I thought this would be possible by creating this function `function trust_wc_sku() {

 global $product;
 return $product->get_sku();
}
` and then calling this as a shortcode inplace of the sku field. sorry if this is completley wrong, im out of my depth here

Comment: It all depends from where you want to do it. Your question doesn't seems clear for me sorry. Please give a pseudo example.

But you can set attributes with jquery.

Comment: I want to be able to add that widget to my product page template. But instead of it having a static sku assigned I need to to be dynamic so that it gets the sku of the product page it is loaded on. I just want to do it in the easiest way possible. Do you think the shortcode option could work or is there an inherent issue with what I was trying to do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tried with jquery? The have even a function for reassign data attributes.